# Crystal Reports - Prompt for Total Page Count

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, count, report, prompt

I have a report that I'm using to create individual shipping labels for product delivery. Company Name, Address, additional fields are all straight forward and drag and drop into report, requiring little manipulation.

My issue comes about in trying to determine how I can prompt the user for the quantity of labels needed for print. This will change from shipment to shipment based on how many boxes are required to fulfill the order. Each box requires its own shipping label. I would simply have the user specify quantity at the "copies" section of the print screen but I also need a field on the label stating n of m so the customer knows total boxes shipped and has an identifier for each individual box. For this reason, I'm curious if and how I can prompt the user before print to provide "total page count", where I can then create the number of needed documents and increment per label using the "page number" field, creating a prompted n of m function.

"Total page count" and "page number" are special fields that I seem to have little access in manipulating so if you know how I can prompt a user for necessary label quantity "total page count" then increment per label with "page number",(to achieve an incrementing N of M function where M is defined by the user) in this manner or another let me know.

Thanks,

Travis

Comment: To the extent i understood you can just create a parameter with number datataype and use it to get the input from user

Comment: Using select expert? Keep in mind that I don't have a database field that reflects the number of labels I need. This variable value won't be known until shipping can determine how many boxes are needed for the order. At that point they'll input the number. Again since I have no database field to link to I don't know that creating a parameter and then associating it with a database field will work. It would if I could access the "total page count" field in select expert but I can't as it's a "special field". Should I be able to?

Comment: Creating parameter doesn't mean that you should always link in select expert with a database field for the paramter to get in use... my point is create a paramter place somewhere in report and hide it....this case also when refresh report parameter will be prompted... let me know if this works

Comment: Hey Siva, Thanks for the help. Additionally, I'm sorry maybe I'm overlooking something but I was able to create the quantity prompt earlier today but am still stuck on how to assign that value to the total page count field.

Comment: Can you post some code on what you have done so that i can understand

Comment: Honestly, thus far there has been little coding involved. Feel free to take a look at the file here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0jh9x1lqwddju1/ShippingLabelShipmentDeliv.rpt?dl=0
You'll see at the bottom right corner of the label I've got {Page Number} of {@Quantity}. "@Quantity" being a parameter and prompt. I can throw in the prompted quantity number in the "@Quantity" field but can't figure out how to then tell "page number" to increment and create numerous copies based on the number filled into the @quantity field, ultimately achieving a variable n of m function.